# JSON Jquery For Loop

Tags: jquery, json

Im using JSON to pull information from an array but my loop doesn't seem to work as it only pulls the first entry and doesn't display them all.

```
function(f) {
    $('#navigation').text(f.alsotaking[0][1]);
    for(var i = 0; i < f.alsotaking; i++) {
        $('#navigation').text(f.alsotaking[i]);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you show the actual JSON ... probably we would know

Comment: It will never display them all, because in the loop you're constantly overriding the text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have this HTML

```
<ul id="navigation"></ul>
```

your JS should look like::

```
var Obj = {
  "alsotaking":[
    ["bla","Software Engineering",1],
    ["bla","Mobile Applications",11],
    ["bla","Practical Networks",71],
    ["bla","Digital Forensics",53]
  ]
};

function readObjArray(ob){
  var contents = "";                         // Prepare string
  for(var i=0; i<ob.length; i++){
    contents += "<li>"+ ob[i][1]+'</li>'; // Fill-in string with HTML
  }
  $('#navigation').html( contents );         // Add html to element
}

readObjArray( Obj.alsotaking );                         // Send Obj to your function
```

or like:

```
function navFromObject( obj ) {
  var HTMLstr = ""; 
  $.each(obj, function(k,v){
      HTMLstr += "<li>"+v[1]+"</li>"; 
  });
  $('#navigation').html( HTMLstr );
}

navFromObject( Obj.alsotaking );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var text='';
for(var i=0; i<f.alsotaking.length;i++){
    text+= ' ' + f.alsotaking[i][1];
}
$('#navigation').text(f.alsotaking[i][1]);
```

Note the "length" in the for loop

Comment: This is not quite correct as it will override `.text()` at every iteration

Comment: Missed that, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

```
function(f){
    $('#navigation').text(f.alsotaking[0][1]);
    $.each( f.alsotaking, function( key, value ) {
      $('#navigation').text(value);
    });
}
```

you can do something like this